# Getting data from MongoDB+Node.js to a client side JavaScript

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to connect to MongoDB with Node.js? And then pass the result to a client side JavaScript and display in HTML.

```
var http = require('http');
var URL = require('url');
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var client = new Db('people', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}), { safe: false });

client.open(function (err, client) {
  client.collection('people', listAllData);
});

var listAllData = function (err, collection) {
  collection.find().toArray(function (err, results) {
    console.log(results);
  });
}
```

Comment: Use the framework mongoose. Found here http://mongoosejs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Mongoose - elegant mongodb object modeling for node.js. http://mongoosejs.com

The quickstart guide is really cool, you should [read it](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html).

According to the documentation, here is a small example of how to use Mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });
var Cat = db.model('Cat', schema);

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('meow');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer MongoJS to Mongoose because it uses the same syntax used by the MongoDB Client syntax
https://github.com/gett/mongojs

```
// simple usage for a local db
var db = mongojs('mydb', ['mycollection']);

// the db is on a remote server (the port default to mongo)
var db = mongojs('example.com/mydb', ['mycollection']);

// we can also provide some credentials
var db = mongojs('username:password@example.com/mydb', ['mycollection']);

// connect now, and worry about collections later
var db = mongojs('mydb');
var mycollection = db.collection('mycollection');
```

Then you can use the same syntax as the Mongo Client

```
db.mycollection.find({}, function(err, docs) { ... });

db.mycollection.find({}).limit(2).skip(1, function(err, docs) { ... });
```