# MongoJS limit and Skip

Tags: node.js, mongojs

I need to use limit and skip to get some record from mongo.

I am using MongoJS with NodeJS but below given is not working.

Below is an example:

```
db.users.find(function(err,doc{
  console.log(doc);
})).skip(2).limit(2);
```

also I have tried something like:

```
db.users.find({ skip:0, limit: 5 }, function(err, results) { 
  console.log(results);
});
```

I am new to JS/NodeJS/MongoJS ,Please let me know how can I use above code correctly .

Comment: see following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701246/getting-data-from-mongodbnode-js-to-a-client-side-javascript/15023340#15023340

Comment: Very good use of queries to answer the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried and found - The correct code is -

```
db.users.find({}).limit(2).skip(0, function(err, docs) { console.log(docs); });
```

Might It can help others.
If any other suggestions are there please share.